# sending a parameter with Link_to and Data-no-turbolink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

The following is very confusing to me:

The first link is correctly not using turbo links but the query is not being sent
The second link is the opposite scenario

```
 = link_to 'yesturbo_noquery', "/controller/action", "data-no-turbolink" => true,   query: "hello"
 = link_to "noturbo_yesquery", {'data-no-turbolink' => true, :controller => "controller", :action => "action", :query => "hello" }
```

How do I make both work?

Edit, This works Thanks to Sikachu

```
 = link_to 'yesturbo_yesquery', controller_action_path(:query => 'hello'), "data-no-turbolink" => true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link_to` method actually consist of 3 parts:

```
link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

From both of the example you wrote there, example 1 mixed in `query` into the `html_options`, and example 2 mixed in `data-no-turbolink` into `options`.

I think if you changed it to this, it will work:

```
link_to 'noturbo_yesquery', {:controller => 'controller', :action => 'action', :query => 'query'}, :data-no-turbolink => true
```

Comment: Or better yet, if you have path helper, you can substitute that controller/action/query hash into something like `action_controller_path(:query => 'query')`

Comment: turbo links doesn't activate with this one, I see the query though.

Comment: Posted too fast; This one supposed to be 'noturbo_yesquery' .. is that the behavior you desired?

Comment: I want both, to have no turbo and see the query. this part :data_no_turbolink => true doesn't get activated for some reason.

Comment: okay solved, in your link it should be "data-no-turbolink" => true

Comment: Ha, yes, it supposed to be dashed. Updating the answer. :D

Answer (score 2):

I think following code is more correct:

```
<%= link_to('Product', @product, data: { no_turbolink: true }) %>
```

Also following code will works:

```
<%= link_to('Product', @product, 'data-no-turbolink' => true) %>
```